# Does pre-receive hook works only on server-side?

Tags: git, github, githooks

I would like to force including jira ticket into commit message. To do it globally I can use pre-receive hook, which is available for GitHub Enterprise, but firstly I would like to test, so in `.git/hooks` directory, I modified `pre-receive.sample -> pre-receive` and added:

```
HOOK_FILE=$1
COMMIT_MSG=`head -n1 $HOOK_FILE`
PATTERN="[MM\-[0-9]+\]"
if [[ ! ${COMMIT_MSG} =~ $PATTERN ]]; then
  echo ""
  echo "    ERROR: Bad commit message."
  echo "    '$COMMIT_MSG' is missing JIRA Ticket Number."
  echo "    ERROR: Please fix the commit message."
  echo "    example: 'MM-1234 my commit'."
  echo ""
  exit 1
fi
```

and after push it doesn't work, but when I move this code into `commit-msg` file, after invalid commit I get message with error. So my question is - am I able to test pre-receive hook modifying only `.git/hooks/pre-receive` on my local repo?

Comment: "*…am I able to test pre-receive hook modifying only .git/hooks/pre-receive on my local repo?*" Yes but you need to push to the repo. There is no magic in Git servers, you can push to any repo, even locally. Git prefers pushing to bare repos so you can create a bare repo for the test and debug `.git/hooks/pre-receive` in it.

Comment: "*There is no magic in Git servers…*" Well, I'm a bit oversimplified. There is some magic when you push locally — Git runs server-side hooks in the client. :-) But that's completely hidden from the user and doesn't require any setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hook [pre-receive](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive) does not take parameters, so it does not work to get the value from `$1`. Github provides some good pre-receive [samples](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/tree/master/pre-receive-hooks) in Bash, among which I think you can find a suitable one and modify it to meet your needs. Remember to name it `pre-receive`.

You can test the pre-receive hook in a local repository which serves as a server-side repository. Here is an example.

```
# create a bare repository that works as a remote repository
git init --bare server
```

Here is a very simple pre-receive.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo HELLO WORLD from the server
```

Make it executable and copy it under `server/hooks`.

```
# clone the repository and name it client
git clone server client 

# edit and commit
cd client
touch a.txt
git add a.txt
git commit -m "init"

# push the branch to server
git push origin master
```

The push will invoke `pre-receive` under `server/hooks` if it is setup correctly. The push prints something like

```
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 202 bytes | 202.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: HELLO WORLD from the server
To /path/to/server/
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

The lines that start with `remote:` are sent back from the server repository. In this example, `remote: HELLO WORLD from the server` is generated by the pre-receive hook.

This way, you can modify and test the hook in the local machine.

Comment: Nice! I didn't realize I can run server just like that. Thanks!

Comment: but to be honest I have one more question - when we commit our changes and our hook don't accept this push because of reasons, shouldn't changes on local be set again as new/modified?

Comment: @Frendom The hook runs in the server-side repository and sends back the rejection reason. The user is expected to redo the commits to solve the issues and push them again until the push is not rejected.